# Problem using Casio fx-991CE X calculator to solve "e^(i*pi)"

Tags: complex-numbers, calculator

I'm trying to solve **e^(i*pi)** on a **Casio fx-991CE X** calculator.

The calculator is in **Complex** mode (MENU>2:Complex).

I Input **e^(i*pi)** and press "=" and get an **error message** instead of **-1**.

What am I missing? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, mine does the same thing. It probably wasn't programmed to recognise $e^{ix}$, but it does recognise $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, which is equivalent.

Comment: [+1] Said slightly differently, "exp" function is hopefuly designed so as to compute the _real_ exponential function.